# Did Sherlock Holmes have a character development arc across Arthur Conan Doyle's books?

Tags: character-analysis, arthur-conan-doyle, sherlock-holmes

Often, in a large novel, a character would have a character development arc, which is considered an integral part of writing.

But Sherlock Holmes canon consists mostly of smaller stories.

Was there a cross-story character development arc for Holmes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible case of character development is in "The Adventure of the Three Garridebs" when Holmes, for the first and only time in all the canon, is shown to care for his fellow man. This may be more *revealing* the character that's always been hidden beneath, rather than a *change* in character, but from an out-of-universe point of view at least, I think it counts as character development:

> "You're not hurt, Watson? For God's sake, say that you are not hurt!"
>
> It was worth a wound - it was worth many wounds - to know the depth of loyalty and love which lay behind that cold mask. The clear, hard eyes were dimmed for a moment, and the firm lips were shaking. For the one and only time I caught a glimpse of a great heart as well as of a great brain. All my years of humble but single-minded service culminated in that moment of revelation.

This is quite a change from the utterly cold, logical, even ruthless man we've seen in Holmes in all the other stories - the man who disdains any distraction from the pursuit of pure reason.

Comment: And, of course, *The Woman*.

Comment: @muru Irene Adler? I don't think that was really an exception to Holmes's adherence to pure logic. He respected her as a formidable opponent; there was never anything romantic or even affectionate in it.

Comment: He also respected Moriarty's intellect, but Moriarty wasn't *The Man*. Even if there wasn't anything romantic or affectionate, that he had a specific euphemism for her indicates she was something emotionally special for him.

Comment: @muru I always took that more as Holmes not thinking women in general were as intellectually formidable as men. This certainly wouldn't have been an uncommon view at the time. He calls her _The Woman_ because she's the single woman who is his equal (in his mind), whereas among men, Holmes holds at least Moriarty and his brother Mycroft at his own level.

Comment: @Torisuda (He's not ashamed to admit that Mycroft is *above* his own level.) There's a quote, in either "A Scandal in Bohemia" or "The Five Orange Pips" IIRC, which goes something like, "I am not infallible. In the course of my career I have been defeated by four men and one woman."

Comment: @Randal'Thor *The Five Orange Pips*, and the quote is “I have been beaten four times – three times by men, and once by a woman.”

Answer (score 10):

There wasn't much development. Most of the stories are short stories, and they rely upon the relationships established for the series - Holmes as the genius, Watson as the storyteller and the person to whom Holmes explains. And occasionally Lestrade as the failing regular police, to show why Holmes is needed in the setting.

Sir Arthur Conan Doyle did try to get rid of the character; having Holmes murdered by Moriarty, and by telling us that Holmes retired to become a beekeeper in "His Last Bow".

The preface to *The Case Book of Sherlock Holmes* is telling:

> I fear that Mr. Sherlock Holmes may become like one of those popular tenors who, having outlived  their  time,  are  still  tempted  to  make  repeated  farewell  bows  to  their  indulgent audiences. This must cease and he must go the way of all flesh, material or imaginary.

So, the main character became stuck in his role early on, to the point that the writer himself considered it monotonous. If Sir Arthur Conan Doyle could have broken this "monotony" by adding character development, he probably would have.